# SQL Server select all records that do not have duplicate value with prefix

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following table:

```
Url
--------------
Id Url
1  foo.com
2  www.foo.com
3  bar.com
4  baz.com
5  www.baz.com
```

How would I go about selecting only the URLs that do not have a corresponding record with a 'www.' prefix? (In this example, the desired result would be to return only `bar.com`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.url not like 'www.%' and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where 'www.' + t.url = t2.url);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/26310) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: This simply returns all the rows that do not have a 'www.' prefix (`foo.com, bar.com, baz.com`), whereas the desired result was to return only rows that do not have a duplicate with the 'www.' prefix somewhere else in the table (just `bar.com`).

Answer (score 1):

you could use replace and group by for filter the single results

```
select  replace( Url 'www.', '')  
from my_table 
group by  replace( Url 'www.', '')
having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: I think, sql server does not support `group by` with alias.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve it using  [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select url from (
    select SUBSTRING(url, CHARINDEX('www', url) * 5, len(url)+1) url  
    from Table1
) as T group by url
having count(url)=1
```

[SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/541bc/11)

Answer (score 0):

You also can do it like there

```
select t.*
from as t
outer apply (
  select 1 as IsExistWithWWW
  from t as t2 
  where lower(t2.url) = lower(replace(t.url, 'www.', ''))
) as a
where lower(t.url) not like 'www.%'
  and a.IsExistWithWWW is null
```

Use lower for make script stronger